# prevent Drupal from loading jquery.min.js from Google

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I have a **Drupal** website that is hosted on **Chinese** Aliyun cloud and visited by Chinese visitors.

The theme is **Velocity**.

The thing is, the first time someone visits the homepage (or with the cache cleared), it **takes ~1+ minute to load the page.**

By looking at the Web Console from Chrome, it shows a GET request pending (and then failing after a while) for **jquery.min.js** from the **Google servers** *(which cannot be accessed from China)*, in particular :

`GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1`

I already tried different configurations of the jQuery update module, e.g. using Microsoft or jQuery as the CDN host, using None, disabling the module entirely etc., but the request keep getting through.

I would like the website to load the jquery.min.js locally from the server, but I am not sure which file to edit : i have added the following line in the **html.tpl.php** *(both in /sites/all/themes/velocity/templates and /sites/default/all/themes/velocity/templates)* , and **template.php** *(in /sites/all/themes/velocity/ and /sites/default/all/themes/velocity)*, but the pending request was still being made.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Is there a way to completely **prevent** the GET request to the Google Servers and just load the file **locally**?

I have looked at many other answers/replies, but I am missing exactly what files should I edit.

Thank you all for your time, and I apologize in advance for the probably trivial question.

Comment: Do you have the jQuery Update module installed? If so, go to /admin/config/development/jquery_update and change the CDN options at the bottom to "None"

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a direct answer to the question, only a few hints.

Taking this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/50748 there should be some code in your theme like the following, which is responsible for inluding the JS by CDN

```
function mytheme_js_alter(&$javascript) {
    $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['type'] = 'external';
    $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
}
```

On this page, you can see other possible ways of including JS in Drupal, which your theme might use: http://wearepropeople.com/blog/7-ways-to-add-custom-js-and-css-to-a-page-in-drupal